# Get permission_required to return True if any permission in a list of permissions is allowed

Tags: django

In 1.7 the permission_required method also accepts a list of permissions, however it only returns True if ALL of the permissions in the list are permitted. I need it to return True if any of the permissions are permitted.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use [user_passes_test](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/):

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def manage_access(user):
    permissions_list = ['app.perm1', 'app.perm2', 'app.perm3', ]

    for permission in permissions_list:
        if user.has_perm(permission):
           return True

    return False

@user_passes_test(manage_access)
def my_view(request):
    #view code
```

If you need anything more complex (e.g: permission list varies based on the view), I'd consider writing a custom decorator.

Comment: I ended up writing a custom decorator. Thanks!